# jquery scroll animation on div

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

When i press a link in the menu bar i want to scroll towards that div with the use of anchors.

My jquery knowledge is non existent, so i appreciate all the help.
This is the site i'm talking about: http://ma-jo.org/

Menu structure:

> This is my header
>                 Here are my menu links: index, about, contact
>                
>                        
>                        
>                        
>                
>                This is my footer

Comment: Why did you remove your markup?

Comment: Because it didn't show right.

Comment: Please accept one of the answers, if you think you have got the correct answer :)

Comment: readout about jquery's `.animate()` function and animate the corresponding `div` or `html,body`. There are lots of questions are answered here already. You can try them out too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to Scroll towards the `DIV` with an animation. You can achieve this task by using [jQuery.ScrollTo Plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/).

This site has some nice demos which you can check on.

This how you do it:
Include these two jquery files inside your `<head></head>` tags

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">   <!--JQuery 1.9.1 (Latest) JS-->
<script src="http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"> <!--Scroll to Plugin-->
```

And now add the following jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu_index a').click(function(){
    $('body').scrollTo( '#footer', 800 );
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried that but it won't animate my divs and i can't figure out why.
The only thing i can think of is because my menu is in another div.

Comment: @user2273523 i have updated my answer pls check :)

Answer (score 0):

No need for jQuery I guess. Check out this page:
http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm

Comment: That's what i have now but i want to add an animation.

Comment: @user2273523 you can add animation using the jQuery.ScrollTo Plugin. Check my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

The following might give you a good starting point.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <div id="menu_index">
        <a href="#content_index">index</a>
        </div>
        <div id="menu_overOns">
        <a href="#content_overOns">over ons</a>
        </div>
        <div id="menu_contact">
        <a href="#content_contact">contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content_all">
        <div id="content_index">
        <a href="#menu">Index</a>
        </div>
        <div id="content_overOns">
        <a href="#menu">overOns</a>
        </div>
        <div id="content_contact">
        <a href="#menu">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu a').on('click', function(ev) { 
        var dest = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content_all').animate({scrollTop: $(dest).position().top },'slow'); 
        ev.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Test it over here at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TJr6k/